# Touch SDK Expansion

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

In the Ubuntu Touch SDK description http://design.ubuntu.com/apps/building-blocks/expansion there is an UI element which is mentioned, namely the Expansion. From the description I don't really understand if there it is a proper UI element or a property of another UI element(like the List View, since in the example it is applied to it).
Since I think this feature is useful and I want to use it for one of my projects can someone explain to me how I can use it? Or is it now still implemented?

Thanks!